# AWS S3 bucket redirection with https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I try to make a redirection from one to another domain.
It is what I have:

Route53 (basic.domain.com) -> S3 bucket (with redirection to example.domain.com) -> example.domain.com

and this scenario works fine:
**http**://basic.domain.com redirects to example.domain.com

but here I get a timeout:
**https**://basic.domain.com redirects to example.domain.com

I probably should put CloudFront between Route53 and S3 bucket but I am looking for a real redirection.
I mean when I type http://basic.domain.com I want to see example.domain.com on the browser address bar.

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Comment: I found a solution. 
To do this I had to use the addition ec2 instance which redirects traffic to example.domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

According to this document:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html

> Important
>
> **Amazon S3 website endpoints do not support HTTPS. For information
> about using HTTPS with an Amazon S3 bucket, see the following:**
>
> How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?
>
> Requiring HTTPS for communication between viewers and CloudFront

Comment: I understand why I have this problem, but I do now know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer said, you can't use `https` with s3 weburl. If you want to add https to your static website in s3, you should **front it with CloudFront** (CF):

- [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/)

If you do this, you will set your `basic.domain.com` to **point to the CF** distro that you will create. Also in the CF distro you will be able to redirect http to https. This is not something S3 buckets can do.

Comment: Hi Marcin,
But that what I would like to achieve is that when I type 
http://basic.domain.com I want to see example.domain.com on the browser address bar.
I am looking for real redirection with a changed URL.

Comment: @KeyB0rys You still need CF for any https for your S3 website. So you would have to redirect to different url which points again to your existing or new CF distro.

Comment: I created something like this:
Route53 (basic.domain.com) -> CF -> S3 bucket (with redirection) -> example.domain.com
but in this case when I go to basic.domain.com I see content of example.domain.com but with basic.domain.com  URL in the browser address bar

Comment: @KeyB0rys I think you may need to redirect from CF then, as shown in [Example: Generating an HTTP Redirect (Generated Response)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect). Not quite sure at present if redirections from S3 only will work. If not, then you have to check the link.